# Cannot access grouped data in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which I can sort by any given value. Later I can group this list by the same key that I used to sort it:

```
oFile = csv.reader(open(FileCsv,"r"), delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
routers = list(oFile)    
routers_sorted=sorted(routers, key=itemgetter(0))
groups = groupby(routers_sorted, key=itemgetter(0))
```

So far so good. Thing is I do not know how to access the data of the grouped list:

```
for i,rou in enumerate(groups): print i,rou
0 ('10.2.53.6', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681850>)
1 ('10.2.54.10', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681890>)
2 ('10.2.54.33', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681850>)
3 ('10.2.54.35', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681890>)
4 ('10.2.54.8', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681850>)
5 ('10.2.56.58', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f2585681890>)
```

Actually each group has many fields inside of it. Look for example:

```
for i,rou in enumerate(routers_sorted): print i,rou
0 ['10.2.53.6', '4001']
1 ['10.2.54.10', '4001']
2 ['10.2.54.10', '5000']
3 ['10.2.54.33', '4001']
4 ['10.2.54.33', '5000']
5 ['10.2.54.35', '4001']
6 ['10.2.54.35', '5000']
7 ['10.2.54.8', '4001']
8 ['10.2.54.8', '5000']
9 ['10.2.56.58', '4001']
10 ['10.2.56.58', '5000']
```

So for key '10.2.54.33' y have two records: '5000' and '4001'. How do I access those once the list has been grouped?

Comment: Have you tried `list(<itertools._grouper object>)`?

Comment: Hi @tobias_k, thanks! Indeed, your suggestion is fine. I did `for rou in enumerate(groups): routers_grouped.append(list(rou[1]))` and I can now access the data for each key ... thank you! Lucas

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. Those `grouper` objects are special iterators, and you could just turn them into lists, e.g. in a loop or a list comprehension.

```
>>> for i, group in groups:
>>>     print i, list(group)
...
10.2.54.10 [['10.2.54.10', '4001'], ['10.2.54.10', '5000']]
...
```

But it might be more useful to create a dictionary, mapping the key you grouped by to just the other values:

```
>>> group_dict = {i: map(itemgetter(1), group) for i, group in groups}
{'10.2.54.8': ['4001', '5000'], 
 '10.2.53.6': ['4001'], 
 '10.2.56.58': ['4001', '5000'], 
 '10.2.54.10': ['4001', '5000'], 
 '10.2.54.33': ['4001', '5000'], 
 '10.2.54.35': ['4001', '5000']}
```

Of course, you could actually skip the `groupby` and just use a `dict` and a loop:

```
group_dict = {}
for key, val in routers_sorted:
    group_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Or, if order is important, do the same with an `OrderedDict`